# Is there an AND option on the rules condition in .gitlab-ci.yml?

Tags: logic, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I want to create some nested conditions: i need this pipeline to work when it is a merge or merge request and with certain name start "feature". So, is there an AND condition in the 'only' option for jobs?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

No there is not. You must use [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules).

```
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "test"
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TITLE =~ /^feature/'
```

Comment: While you can have multiple `if` statements. Combined with `when`, right?

Comment: Is multiline possible so the && chain stays readable?

Comment: @andymel as far as I know that's unfortunately not possible. Multiline commands can only be used in `script`, `before_script` and `after_script`

Comment: @andymel - whiel you can't have them "chained" with the - > or - | ([multiline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/script.html#split-long-commands)) you can use brackets such as `( condition1 && condition2 && condition3 )` and put each condition in new line. Keep in mind that each line has to be indented correctly, which you can verify using the [pipeline editor](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipeline_editor/).

See such example [here](https://hastebin.app/62711ec2d3810c001cf24b68).

Comment: Updated relevant doc link: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#group-variable-expressions-together-with-parentheses

Answer (score 1):

There's another operator that the AND operator.
You can replace the `AND` in your the gitlab-ci.yml file with the `&&` operator. That's how we make it !