# Does GitLab CI rules reference follow `and` or `or` condition?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, pipeline, cicd, gitlab-ci.yml

I have some rules for example:

```
.run_for_apple:
  - if: '$APPLE == "apple"'
.run_for_orange:
  - if: '$ORANGE == "orange"'
```

I wonder if in my job as below:

```
job_one:
....
rules:
  - !reference [.run_for_apple]
  - !reference [.run_for_orange]
```

Does GitLab ci consider the rule as an `and` condition or an `or` condition?
I could not find an explicit explanation. Please let me know if anyone knows anything!

I have seen sometimes the job run when the first rule is true while other rules are false.

Comment: After investigation, it seems to me that the multiple rules tend to work in an `or` manner condition. If we want an `and` condition, we need to explicitly use `&&` continuously.

Comment: Indeed. Since Gitlab evaluates array of `- if:`'s sequentially in order until first match (means, ignoring whatever goes further), you can read it as _OR_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67219330/is-there-an-and-option-on-the-rules-condition-in-gitlab-ci-yml