# Using both rules:changes and rules:if on gitlab ci

Tags: yaml, gitlab-ci

I have a variable named `$DEPLOY_STAGE` for each job, and it's default value is false. I want to create a rule, where if either the variable is set to true or there was a change in the directory corresponding with the job, then the job is added to the pipeline. I used the following rule on each job:

```
rules:
  - changes:
      - "job/**/*"
    when: on_success
  - if: '$DEPLOY_STAGE == "true"'
    when: on_success
```

The changes part works fine, but when I manually run the pipeline and set a single variable to true, all jobs are added to the pipeline. What could be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules) are OR'd by default ([not AND](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67219330/6309)), meaning a job will be added to the pipeline if any of the listed conditions are met.
The `changes` keyword only takes effect when there are changes to track, such as when a new commit is pushed to a branch. In a manually triggered pipeline, the `changes` condition is not met because there are no changes to evaluate. So, all jobs are evaluated based on the `$DEPLOY_STAGE == "true"` condition only.

To achieve the desired behavior where the job is added to the pipeline if either the variable is set to true or there is a change in the directory, you might have to use the `script` keyword in combination with `rules`.

```yaml
job_name:
  script:
    - echo "Job tasks go here."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"'
      changes:
        - "job/**/*"
    - if: '$DEPLOY_STAGE == "true"'
```

That will add the job to the pipeline if either there is a change in the `job/**/*` directory when the pipeline source is a push operation, or if the `$DEPLOY_STAGE` variable is set to "true" (regardless of the pipeline source).

I assume the `$DEPLOY_STAGE` variable is not being set globally to "true", because if it was... that would cause all jobs to run regardless of changes.

---

> So if I am using trigger it will not work?

Correct, if you are using manual triggers or scheduled pipelines, the `changes` keyword generally does not evaluate to true, as there are usually no new changes to compare against the previous pipeline. That would mean that the second rule (`if: '$DEPLOY_STAGE == "true"`) will dictate whether the job is included, and if you set `$DEPLOY_STAGE` to "true", it will include all jobs that have this condition.

For your specific case, you may need to employ a different strategy to conditionally include jobs based on both file changes and the `$DEPLOY_STAGE` variable when dealing with manual triggers. You could, for example, write a custom script that performs the directory comparison and sets an environment variable based on the result. That variable can then be used in your `rules` to conditionally include or exclude jobs.

That different strategy could involve using a [`before_script` section](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#before_script) to execute a custom script that checks for changes in the specific directories and sets an environment variable based on the result. That environment variable can then be used in the `rules` block.

```yaml
before_script:
  - |
    if git diff --name-only $CI_COMMIT_BEFORE_SHA $CI_COMMIT_SHA | grep -q "job/"; then
      export DIRECTORY_CHANGED=true
    else
      export DIRECTORY_CHANGED=false
    fi

job_name:
  script:
    - echo "Job tasks go here."
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $DIRECTORY_CHANGED == "true"'
    - if: '$DEPLOY_STAGE == "true"'
```

The `before_script` runs a `git diff` command that looks for changes between the last and current commits within the `job/` directory. If it finds any, it sets an environment variable `$DIRECTORY_CHANGED` to "true".

Then in the `rules` for the specific job, we use this `$DIRECTORY_CHANGED` variable along with `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` to determine whether the job should run or not. That way, the job will run if either `$DEPLOY_STAGE` is "true" or if there is a push event and the directory has changed.

Note that the above `git diff` command assumes you have a shallow clone of the repository available in your runner, with history sufficient to cover the commit range you are interested in. Depending on your setup, you might need to adjust the depth of the Git clone operation.

Comment: So if I am using trigger it will not work?

Comment: @nadavyaf I have expanded on what that "different strategy" could look like.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put it out there, if there is no push on a job, changes automatically evaluate to `true` not false.

Be careful with this one. I triggered a build storm by manually triggering (clicking run pipeline in the GUI) our top level job to see what would happen.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#ruleschanges

Specifically:

```
You should use rules: changes only with branch pipelines or merge request pipelines. You can use rules: changes with other pipeline types, but rules: changes always evaluates to true for new branch pipelines or when there is no Git push event. Pipelines like tag pipelines, scheduled pipelines, and manual pipelines, all do not have a Git push event associated with them. In these cases, use rules: changes: compare_to to specify the branch to compare against.
```